# HighCharts: Tooltip for customized drawing

Tags: highcharts

We have an application to draw some bioinformatics images. HighCharts.js is a very good plotter. I know that we may define the tooltip by the API:

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() { 
        return 'here the html code';
    }
},
```

But how to add a tooltip for the customized parts? Say add a tooltip for labels [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/renderer/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the default tooltip of Highchart on custom objects. `renderer.text`, `renderer.label`, etc... because they return `SVGObject`.

The solution is to create your own tooltip. I would suggest you to use a predefined tooltip library like twitter boostrap :

```
// your tooltip created with bootstrap
$(".yourlabel").tooltip({
// ^^^^^^^^^^
    'container': '#container',
    'placement': 'top',
    'title': 'Mytooltip'
});

// with
ren.label('Rasterized image', 100, 215)
    .attr({
         'class': 'yourlabel'
         //        ^^^^^^^^^
    })
    .css({
         color: colors[1],
         fontSize: '10px'
    })
    .add();
```

You can see that we link the tooltip with your custom object thanks to the `class` attribute. If you choose to use the twitter bootstrap tooltips, don't forget to use the `container` attribute. It will not work without it...

Here is a live example : http://jsfiddle.net/rttav/

And this is the documentation for twitter boostrap tooltips : http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the title field is used as a tooltip (no need for jquery-ui) :

```
renderer.circle(200, 150, 100).attr({
    fill: '#FCFFC5',
    stroke: 'black',
    title:'Hello\nI am a \nmultiline tooltip',
    'stroke-width': 1
}).add();
```

In action : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Snarkturne/NYZNT/

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in option for custom elements tooltip, however you can add your own tooltip to each element. Just use `on()` function, something like that:

```
ren.path(...).attr(...).add().on('mouseOver', function () { alert ('mouseOver!'); }).on('moueOut', function () { alert('mouseOut'); });
```